# Returning a parent class - Inheritance

Tags: c#, .net

I have a parent class

```
public class User
{
    public int UserKey { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the class below that inherits from `User`

```
public class MyInfo : User
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a utility class that returns a type of `User`. However I want to use the same method for `MyInfo` and only fill out whatever `MyInfo` inherited from `User`. The method can be found below:

```
public static User fetchUserInformation()
{
    User user = new User()
    //fetch data..
    return user;
}
```

What I’m doing is

```
MyInfo myinfo = fetchUserInformation();
```

but this wouldn’t work since `fetchUserInformation` returns a type of `User`.

Comment: Do you want to return `MyInfo` instead of `User` object?  Can you elaborate `how i can have that method fill out User in MyInfo and leave the rest empty?` What is expected output?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking, Please clarify "*how i can have that method fill out User in MyInfo and leave the rest empty*"

Comment: sorry i dont know how to put this. since its a inheritance they have some variables in common. The method that i call returns the result in `User`. `MyInfo` inherits from `User`. What im trying to do is call that same method and only fill out the part that they have in common.

Comment: How are you creating MyInfo ?

Comment: The question is not clear!

Comment: let me edit it with more info

Comment: Inheritance doesn't work that way round. It would allow you to return a reference to a `MyInfo` object and treat that as a `User` reference, but not the other way round. What would you expect `myinfo.name` to do in your example, if the object is only a `User` object? (As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, even in sample code. Unconventional code distracts from what you're actually asking.)

Comment: I just added that as a sample so i could get my point across on how they are different. `User` actually holds general data for everyone but `MyInfo` Holds more specific values that doesnt apply to all `User`s. My bad if it was confusing

Comment: The point is that if you create a `new User()`, you cannot "upcast" it to a more specific `MyInfo`, because it _isn't one_. You have to create a `new MyInfo` to begin with. Show more context and how your code actually initializes those instances.

Comment: Hello @iamaaarianme,is my answer helpful?

Comment: @YiyiYou yes thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to serialize `User` and deserialize it to `MyInfo`.

Change

```
MyInfo myinfo = fetchUserInformation();
```

to

```
MyInfo myInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyInfo>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fetchUserInformation()));
```

Another way,you can try without using inheritance.Here is a demo:

```
public class MyInfo
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }

    }
MyInfo myInfo = new MyInfo { user = fetchUserInformation() };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is how you shoud do it:

```
    public class MyInfo : User
    {
        public string name { get; set; }

    }
    public class User
    {
        public int UserKey { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public void fetchUserInformation()
        {

            Username = "TOTO";

        }
    }


    MyInfo infos = new MyInfo();
    infos.fetchUserInformation();
    Console.WriteLine(infos.Username);
```

Otherwise I think you should do the new outside of the method. Because if you want a MyInfo object you need to do new MyInfo() so maybe pass the user as a parameter ?